# How to cycle OSD mode with mplayer?

Tags: mplayer, osd

I would like to turn off all OSD in mplayer from the command line, but can't find any way other than pressing the "o" key.

I don't want to use a scripted fifo on the headless machine and hope some guru can point me to a command line argument like:

```
mplayer -osd none file.mp4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The manual page for `mplayer` states that the option `-osdlevel 0` will disable the OSD. Note that this puts `mplayer` in the same state as pressing `o o o` but doesn't need a file.

```
  -osdlevel <0-3> (MPlayer only)
          Specifies which mode the OSD should start in.
             0    subtitles only
             1    volume + seek (default)
             2    volume + seek + timer + percentage
             3    volume + seek + timer + percentage + total time
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I could find was to use the following:

```
mplayer -input file=noOSD.conf file.mp4
```

where the contents of noOSD.conf were just simply three lower case letter o's that can easily be created from the command line:

```
echo "o o o" > noOSD.conf
```

Basically this is just like a keyboard trigger and works fine. Absolutely no OSD.